# Storing on/off flags for days of week in SQL - bitmask or string?

Tags: sql, bitwise-operators, sql-like

I want to store a set of flags for days of week to know whether some event will occur today or not. I expect to run lots of SELECTs like `SELECT event_name FROM events WHERE <day_of_week field contains "on" value for today's day of week>`.

I don't see a point to normalize it and use a separate table with seven booleans and 1:1 relation to the events table. But maybe I should?

1. I could store the flags as an integer and then SELECT
   with bitwise & operation.
2. I could store the flags as characters (e.g. "25" would mean that
   the event will occur if today is Tuesday or Friday) and SELECT as
   `like '%2%'` for Tuesday.
3. Are there better options?

Essentially, the main question is: what is generally recommended for better SELECT performance - bitwise & operator or `like`?

Comment: Create another table to store event/date info.

Comment: @jarlh: yes, that would be database normalization. But then I'd have to add JOINs in every select. Also, there won't be any specific dates stored, only day of week, which is just 7 flags, that's why it seems a bit overkill to create a table just for that.

Comment: Why don't you simply use date functions?

Comment: I can use date functions to get current day of week, but I'm not sure how to use it to store the fact that one specific event must occur only on tuesdays and fridays.

Comment: It depends on how much data you're storing and what your query patterns are like. Note that neither bit mask fiddling nor `LIKE '%2%'` can make use of indexes. So, if your data volumes could ever reach the point where indexes are of use... then you'll have to redesign to the normalized form then anyway. And it wouldn't be a table in a 1-1 relationship - it would be a table containing (up to) seven *rows*, not seven columns, because it's the same "type" of data for each day, so it should all appear in one column.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for the normalized approach. So, a second table, along the lines of:

```
CREATE TABLE EventDays (
   EventID int not null, /* Or whatever the PK is for Events */
   DayOfWeek tinyint not null,
   constraint CK_EventDays_DayOfWeek CHECK (DayOfWeek between 0 and 6),
   constraint PK_EventDays PRIMARY KEY (EventID,DayOfWeek),
   constraint FK_EventDays_Events FOREIGN KEY (EventID)
          references Events (EventID) /*Again, PK */
)
```

For an event occurring on Tuesdays and Fridays:

```
INSERT INTO EventDays (EventID,DayOfWeek) VALUES
(@EventID,2),
(@EventID,5)
```

(Assuming `@EventID` is set elsewhere)

And then the query you'd run would be:

```
SELECT event_name FROM events
WHERE EventID IN (
  select EventID from EventDays where DayOfWeek = 2)
```

Normalizing the data has the benefits that the above doesn't actually assume *what* type of queries you're going to write. But it does also have the advantage that indexes *may* be applied, if they're needed. Neither bit masking nor `LIKE` expressions with leading wildcards can *possibly* use indexes.

Answer (score 0):

This may suit your needs

1: Create a table to hold the events with a column for each day of the week

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EventDates](
    [EventID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EventName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Monday] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Tuesday] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Wednesday] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Thursday] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Friday] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_EventDates] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [EventID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

2: Add some test data to the table

```
INSERT EventDates VALUES (1, 'Event1', 'On', 'Off', 'On', NULL, NULL)

INSERT EventDates VALUES (2, 'Event2', 'On', 'On', 'On', NULL, NULL)

INSERT EventDates VALUES (3, 'Event3', 'Off', 'On', 'Off', 'On', 'On')
```

3: Use [UNPIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) to get the days on which an event should run

```
    SELECT
        unpiv.EventName, unpiv.[dayofweek], unpiv.value
    FROM
        EventDates e
    UNPIVOT
    (
        value for [dayofweek] IN (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday)
    ) unpiv
    WHERE
        datename(dw,getdate()) = unpiv.[dayofweek] --get todays events
```

Comment: Why not use a non-nullable `bit` field instead of a nullable varchar 50 that will hold no more than 3 chars?

Comment: @Hans - for production code definitely should be using bit field, however this is just some sample code to help the OP